# Program Hangs when opening Word interop in vb.net on VM

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, interop

I have made a program wthat starts a word file in vb.net. (interop) The program runs on a couple of PC's without a problem.

I have the same program running on a Virtual MAchine on which Office is installed. However, the installtion of MS Office does not help a lot: the program hangs. It does not go into an error but just hangs.

It happens in the next line:

```
 Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
```

I already tried:

```
            Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

But this hangs on the second line. I placed a label for tracking where it exactly hangs while it goes OK on my development PC..

I can not find it and I am stuck. does anybody have an idea what is the reason or Solution?

Comment: We might need more context. What kind of app is this? A service? What kind of VM is it and especially how do you connect to the Desktop of the VM? A Remote Desktop Connection?

Comment: Has Word opened a dialog, possibly hiding behind another window, which needs to be attended to?

Comment: Could be a dead Word instance on that machine. Check the task manager and kill the stuck process if there is one. Could be that Word did open outside of the screen and awaits some user input. If that's the case Word should appear in the taskbar. The window can be moved back into the screen by holding shift, performing a right click  on the symbol in the taskbar and choose maximize (Win 10 and later).

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the good input. Althoug there was no  word open, in the taskmanager I found some Word processen.. Killed them, and it worked. Thanks. this might still be there from the installation by the server administrators who I asked for MSOffice on that VM.
How to mark this question as solved??

Comment: @Ukkie You can answer your own question; how to: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Although you found the cause, I would like to point out that Microsoft Office Interop all runs through COM interface.  Be sure to properly dispose of all of your COM objects when done with them or you will see the target Office application's .exe stacking up in task manager because there is still an open COM on them.  If this happens and too many of those .exe's are running, you will start to see OLE errors in your application.  This from experience.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have a close and dispose at the end but i will keep an eye out if the taskmanager does not also run full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the good input. Althoug there was no word open, in the taskmanager I found some Word processen.. Killed them, and it worked. Thanks. this might still be there from the installation by the server administrators who I asked for MSOffice on that VM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).